# Hikashop: Category Name in products listing div

Tags: joomla-3.x, php7, hikashop

I want to show the category name of a product, inside the category product listing div (category name inside each product div).
I use this code to show manufacturer:

```
<?php
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$db->setQuery('SELECT category_name FROM '.hikashop_table('category').'
WHERE category_id='.(int)$this->row->product_manufacturer_id);
$brandName = $db->loadResult();
?>
<?php
if (!empty($brandName)) {
echo JText::_('MANUFACTURER').': '. $brandName;
} else { echo " ";}
?>
```

Any help?
Thank you

Comment: You shouldn't put database queries inside loops. This is highly inefficient. You'll run a query for each product and end up with duplicate queries (in case multiple products have the same manufacturer). It's better to collect manufacturer IDs, run a single query to get their names and make them accessible in an easy way (e.g. indexed array).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will display the brand name of each product on the listing.
For the category name, you would need to do something like that instead:

```
<?php
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$db->setQuery('SELECT category_name
               FROM ' . hikashop_table('category') . ' AS c
               LEFT JOIN ' . hikashop_table('product_category') . ' AS pc
                   ON c.category_id = pc.category_id
               WHERE pc.product_id = ' . (int)$this->row->product_id);
$categoryName = $db->loadResult();
echo $categoryName;
?>
```

To get a link around the category name, you would do instead:

```
<?php
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$db->setQuery('SELECT category_name
               FROM ' . hikashop_table('category') . ' AS c
               LEFT JOIN ' . hikashop_table('product_category') . ' AS pc
                   ON c.category_id = pc.category_id
               WHERE pc.product_id = ' . (int)$this->row->product_id);
$category = $db->loadObject();
$class = hikashop_get('class.category');
$class->addAlias($category);
echo '<a href="'.hikashop_contentLink('category&task=listing&cid='.$category->category_id.'&name='.$category->alias,$category).'">'.($category->category_name).'</a>';
?>
```

Comment: Is there a way to have the category name as link to that specific category products listing? Thanks.

Comment: I've modified the code in my message above to add the code for the category with the link.

Comment: Thank you, works fine!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you don't need to query the database. Category information is available through `categories` property.

```
// Get category names.
$categories = array_column($this->row->categories, 'category_name');
echo implode(', ', $categories);
```